# loop through and compare all results of two foreach loops?

Tags: loops

I have 2 foreach loops:

Loop 1: goes through a json file

Loop 2: goes through a database

i want to compare the results form the json to the results in the database.

```php
// TRANSACTIONS
$transaction = json_decode(transaction_list($wallet_id), true);

// DATABASE ROWS
$rows = $db->run('SELECT * FROM transactions');

// loop through transactions
foreach ($transaction as $tx) {
    $tx_id = $tx['id'];
}

// loop through database
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
}
echo $id . " | " . $tx_id . "\n";
```

The results are only one line, Id like to get results for all the lines.

> 24d418b322e889e39d8e4bf3b8d6060e479d40032658cb9b080ff6d615eee9cf |
> 7c6c161695a21ad9143b1f3e242d176880b3484ebb1f6c820772c92ece916bdb

How do i get all the results from the database?

I tired a for loop to count the rows and produce one result for each one, but I just got the above line 12 times instead of 12 different results.

The goal is to be able to compare the json files results to the database and if theyre different to insert the json thats not already in the database into the database. for example, if the $tx_id doesnt exist to add the new transaction to the database. Maybe Im doing this wrong?

Comment: Your code only compare the lastest id of objects in json file and rows in database. You can achieve your goal by sql :
```
SELECT * FROM transactions where id NOT EXISTS `your transaction list`
```

Comment: @T.MLuan thanks. could you help me out a little, im not good with SQL queries and Im struggling to make sence of what you said. I cant get "not exist" to work.

Comment: Easier approach:
`SELECT * 
FROM transactions
WHERE id NOT IN ('111z', '22b');`


        '111z', '22b' ... is  the list of transaction you extract from JSON transaction_list.